# How to forward jwt token in Vert.x REST service

Tags: jwt, vert.x

I have a Vert.x REST service that receive requests with jwt tokens, and I want to call my another REST service passing received token. Between router handler and WebClient call I have a business logic layer. My question is if there is a method to provide token to webClient other than passing it explicitly through my business logic layer? In other words is it possible to retrieve somehow my RoutingContext and token from e.g. vertxContext or an other component?

Example code demonstrating what I would like to achieve:

Verticle cass

```
public class RestApiVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    businessLogicService service;

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        initService();

        HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer();
        Router router = Router.router(vertx);

        JWTAuth authProvider = JWTAuth.create(vertx, getAuthConfig());
        router.route("/*").handler(JWTAuthHandler.create(authProvider));

        router.route("/somePath").handler(this::handleRequest);

        server.requestHandler(router::accept).listen(config().getInteger("port"));
    }

    private void handleRequest(RoutingContext context){
        service.doSomeBusinessLogic(); //I could pass context here, but I thing this is not a proper way to do it, as business logic should not know about RequestContext
    }

    private void initService(){
        ExternalAPICaller caller = new ExternalAPICaller(WebClient.create(vertx));
        service = new BusinessLogicService(caller);
    }

    private JsonObject getAuthConfig() {
        return new JsonObject();
    }
}
```

BusinessLogicService:

```
public class BusinessLogicService {
    ExternalAPICaller caller;

    public BusinessLogicService(ExternalAPICaller caller){
        this.caller = caller;
    }

    public void doSomeBusinessLogic(){
        caller.doSth();
    }
}
```

ExternalAPICaller:

public class ExternalAPICaller {
    WebClient client;

```
public ExternalAPICaller(WebClient client){
    this.client = client;
}

public void doSth(){
    String TOKEN = null; // I would like to retrive here my token from some vertx component

    client.post("externalAPIpath")
        .putHeader("Authorization", "Bearer" + TOKEN)
        .send(ctx -> {
            //(..)
        });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

My implementation is in JavaScript (Node.js/Express), but I used cookies to send the JWT to the client.

```
res.cookie("auth", token);
return res.redirect(`http://localhost:3000/socialauthredirect`);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call your do business logic method you could pass the request `authorization` header value as it contains your untouched jwt token. Then on your web client add a header with that value and of course named `authorization` and your token is forwarded to the next service.